# How to fix multiline-string indentation in python-mode?

Tags: indentation, python

When adding the docstring to a fuction

```
def func():
    """|"""
```

After pressing `RET` I have this

```
def func():
    """
"""
```

Instead of this

```
def func():
    """
    |
    """
```

`|` is a cursor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem stems from this check in `electric-indent-post-self-insert-function`:

```el
(defun electric-indent-post-self-insert-function ()
    ...
    (when (and
           electric-indent-mode
           ...
             (let ((act (or (run-hook-with-args-until-success
                             'electric-indent-functions
                             last-command-event)
                            (memq last-command-event electric-indent-chars))))
               (not
                (or (memq act '(nil no-indent))
                    ;; In a string or comment.
                    (unless (eq act 'do-indent) (nth 8 (syntax-ppss))))))))
```

You can get around this by doing:

```el
(defun always-do-indent (_char)
  'do-indent)
(defun my-python-mode-hook ()
  (add-hook 'electric-indent-functions #'always-do-indent nil t))
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook #'my-python-mode-hook)
```

Which will result in:

```py
def foo():
   """
   |"""
```

To get the extra newline in the middle that you want, (assuming you have `electric-pair-mode` enabled) you can add this electric pair mode post self insert hook (adapted from [Stefan's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1283394/stefan) answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/19715115/319698):

```el
(defun python-electric-pair-docstring-delimiter ()
  (when (and electric-pair-mode
             (memq last-command-event '(?\" ?\'))
             (let ((count 0))
               (while (eq (char-before (- (point) count)) last-command-event)
                 (setq count (1+ count)))
               (= count 3)))
    (save-excursion
      (insert ?\n (make-string 3 last-command-event))
      (indent-according-to-mode))
    (newline-and-indent)))

(defun my-python-mode-hook ()
  (add-hook 'post-self-insert-hook
            #'python-electric-pair-docstring-delimiter 'append t))
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook #'my-python-mode-hook)
```

Comment: Well, I've abandoned emacs for now, but as you can see this isn't doing what I wanted. Thanks anyway. Am I right that the core of a problem is that it doesn't indent in strings and comments?

Comment: yes, just like it does for parentheses and brackets etc.

Comment: I was, yes. Sorry I haven't mentioned it.

Comment: The first suggestion works as promised, but the second one doesn't change anything.

Comment: `(make-string 3 last-command-event)` is wrong. It inserts three unneeded quotes. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not talking about taste. Electric pare s inserts closing triple quotes already. So adding another three isn't needed.

Comment: @user1685095 Not for me. `emacs -Q -f electric-pair-mode -f python-mode` type `"""` I get just the 3 quotes, not 6.

Comment: Probably you have old version

Answer (score -1):

I use yasnippet which avoids this problem. after writing function name, type `d` and hit `TAB`, it will expand to multiline string with correct indentation

```
def foo():
   d
```

After hitting `TAB`, it becomes

```
def foo():
   """|
   """
```

You can also write a custom snippet to make it

```
def foo():
   """
   |
   """
```

Comment: Yeah, I use a lot of snippets in vim too, but I can't accept this as an answer. I'm interested in fixing this particular emacs bug, not just solving the problem via workaround. I think something like defadvice should help, but I'm to feeble in elisp.